# Scheduling HS Brackets with Spring Break conflicts

Tags: tournaments, schedule

I'm looking at a non-professional multi-school tournament starting soon with a major issue, that being Spring Break. Many of the schools don't have the same Spring break, and some of the schools will be closed when their matches would take place.

Previously, this has resulted in those schools having to forfeit, because our brackets system is so very basic. Giving them a bye also seems unfair to other schools, since this is an elimination tournament, and the other schools are not required to provide a reschedule.

I'm looking for a bracket design that could understand that some schools can't participate in certain weeks, without in some way giving those schools an advantage (aka bye) or disadvantage (aka forfeit).

Any suggestions?

Comment: What you ask for is impossible. Either every team plays every week or every teams skips some weeks or some teams skip some weeks (either every team skips the same weeks or every team skips the same number of weeks at different times). You've specified that the first option cannot work, so you must choose one of the others.

Comment: Would it be less impossible with a double elimination format, assuming each team misses no more than a single week?

Comment: No, the tournament format changes nothing. Your question requires a contradiction, that some teams are allowed to not play every week but nobody is allowed to not play every week.

Comment: You could just say it requires every team miss one week.

Comment: So, are you okay with giving teams a bye or not? You've said you don't want to provide that advantage in the question, making your own suggestion contrary to it...